# How to prove that a surjection from a dense set to another dense set extends to a surjection?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, order-theory

I am studying the book Discovering Modern Set Theory: The Basics but I am stuck in one important lemma.

*Let $\langle A_0,\leq_0 \rangle$ and $\langle A_1,\leq_1 \rangle$ be dense, complete linear orders without largest or smallest elements, and let $D_0$, $D_1$ be dense subsets of $A_0$ and $A_1$ respectively. For every order-preserving function $f:D_0 \to D_1$ there exists an order preserving function $\tilde{f}:A_0 \to A_1$ such that $\tilde{f}|_{D_0}=f$. Moreover, if $f$ maps $D_0$ onto $D_1$, then $\tilde{f}$ maps $A_0$ onto $A_1$.*

I succeded to prove the part of the extension following the book's guidance, however I'm stuck in this surjection part. I tried proving by contradiction, contrapositive and trying to prove using the definition of the extension that $\tilde{f}$ will be surjective. This function was defined as following: for each $r \in A_0$ let
$$X_r = \{b \in A_1 :  \exists d \in D_0, d \leq_0 r, b\leq_1 f(d)\}$$
and set $f(r)$ as the unique $a \in A_1$ such that
$$X_r \leq_1 a \leq_1 X_r^c$$
which exists because of density and $\{X_r,X_r^c\}$ being a Dedekind cut. Everything I can think of leads me to the idea of sequence or supremum, which we don't have here. Every idea is welcome.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "we don't have" suprema?  These linear orders are complete...

Comment: @EricWofsey , by complete the book means that every Dedekind cut is not a gap, it is, for every Dedekind cut X,Y there is a element a such that $X \leq a \leq Y$. I don't see how this imply that, for example, if I take the set $W$ of all $d \in D_0$ such that $f(d) \leq a$ I can guarantee the existence of a element $r \in A_0$ such that if $d < r$ we have $d \in W$. I said "we don't have" because the book has not mentioned this yet, only maximal/maximum/minimal/minimum elements of a set which I think are a bit different.